# Display only some of the lines of the lsof command

Tags: bash, lsof

I am trying to create a bash script for displaying only certain lines of the lsof command. I have figured out that the lsof command itself lists information in the form of columns which show info about correspondingly: COMMAND    PID   USER   FD   TYPE        DEVICE SIZE/OFF      NODE NAME

How can I modify this info to output just the information about the command and the name of the file using it in format: COMMAND || NAME ?

Comment: So, what have you tried so far? What is not working?

Comment: Well I am not really sure how can I display the info this way. Until now I have tried using lsof -Fcn and it has displayed the commands and the names but in random order and on different lines. I am not really sure what command to use in order to archieve this and I have not managed to find relevant information on the internet.

Comment: `man lsof` lists all the options for controlling lsof output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your attempt with `-F` didn't work as `-F` is meant for a different purpose and will add newline characters after each selected field.

I've no time to wade through the options of `lsof` to maybe coerce it to produce the desired output, as brute forcing it is much easier:

```
lsof | sed -e 's/\s\s*/ /g' | cut -d' ' -f 1,9 | sed -e 's/ / || /'
```

Remove the last `sed` if you don't really want the `||` separator.